# Django blog not linking to detail view

Tags: django

I have a django blog that I'm working on and I've got the first part of the blog working in which the blog displays the various entry's from the database. However when I go to click on a particular blog post it doesn't redirect me to the detailed view, it just kinda redirects me back to the blog where I can see all the blog posts:

By clicking on this in the blog.html I want it to link to the particular post in the post.html

```
<h2><a href="{% url 'entry_detail' slug=object.slug %}">{{ object.title }}</a></h2>
```

urls.py
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
    from . import views, feed

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^feed/$', feed.LatestPosts(), name="feed"),
    url(r'^', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="blog"),
    url(r'^entry/(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="entry_detail"),
)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class Tag(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug


class EntryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def published(self):
        return self.filter(publish=True)


class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    SHIRT_SIZES = (
        ('S', 'Small'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('L', 'Large'),
    )
    shirt_size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SHIRT_SIZES, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = EntryQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("entry_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ["-created"]
```

views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from . import models


class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.Entry.objects.published()
    template_name = "blog.html"
    paginate_by = 3


class BlogDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Entry
    template_name = "post.html"
```

blog.html

```
{% include 'head.html' %}
{% include 'navbar.html' %}

<div class="container">

{% load django_markdown %}
<br>
<br>
{% for object in object_list %}
  <div class="post">
    <h2><a href="{% url 'entry_detail' slug=object.slug %}">{{ object.title }}</a></h2>

      <p class="meta"></p>

      <p class="meta">
          {{ object.created }} |
          Tagged under {{ object.tags.all|join:", " }}
      </p>
      {{ object.body|markdown }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}

    <hr class="featurette-divider">


{% if is_paginated %}
            <ul class="pager">
              <li {% if not page_obj.has_previous %}class="disabled"{% endif %}><a {% if page_obj.has_previous %}href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}"{% endif %}>Prev</a></li>
              <li {% if not page_obj.has_next %}class="disabled"{% endif %}><a {% if page_obj.has_next %}href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}"{% endif %}>Next</a></li>
            </ul>
{% endif %}

    </div>
{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

post.html

```
{% load django_markdown %}

{% for object in object_list %}

  <div class="post">
    <h2><a href="{% url "entry_detail" slug=object.slug %}">{{ object.title }}</a></h2>

    <p class="meta">
      {{ object.created }} |
      Tagged under {{  object.tags.all|join:", " }} <p> Created by
      {{ object.author }} </p>
    </p>
    {{ object.body|markdown }}
  </div>
```

I've also got another url.py which points the blog url to all the urls in the blog app. Don't know if that helps:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'website.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^about/', 'website.views.about', name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/', 'contact.views.contact', name='contact'),
    url(r'^markdown/', include("django_markdown.urls")),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Comment: What does that URL template tag output when you inspect the source?

Comment: it outputs the slug. <a href="/blog/entry/my-second-post">My Second Post</a>

Comment: It could be a case of a pattern overriding another pattern unexpectedly. I always try to order my patterns from the *most* specific to the *least* specific (longest to shortest).

Comment: Yeah I'm guessing its something playing up with the urls because everything else looks correct. I tried to change the patterns around but no dice. Actually I changed around the patterns and restarted the server and its seemed to have changed something. Now its coming up with a blank page... I'll keep working on it

Comment: Works now! Thanks Brandon and rnevius

Comment: Hey @Jimmyn, can you add the solution as an answer?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define the urls with this:

```
url(r'^', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="blog"),
url(r'^entry/(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="entry_detail"),
```

The second entry matches `/entry`, which is not what you expect. I think that in your case, you should define it like this:

```
url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="blog"),
url(r'^entry/(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="entry_detail"),
```

`^$` will match `/`, but not `/entry/...`

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. By cutting off the url at / you don't allow it to match /entry/..ect therefore it doesnt have a conflict and result in the first url in the urls list.

Comment: But you do allow it to match `/entry`...If it doesn't match `/`, it moves on to `/entry`...Unless I'm missing something, this is the correct answer

Comment: @rnevius sorry must of worded that a little bad. yes i agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved thanks to Brandon. Rearranged my url  patterns from the most specific to the least specific (longest to shortest). And restarted the server.

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^entry/(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="entry_detail"),
    url(r'^feed/$', feed.LatestPosts(), name="feed"),
    url(r'^', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="blog"),    
)
```